# How to scrape infinite pages using python scrapy when there is no reference to next page in html

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this e-commerce website [page](https://fr.cocote.com/s/c/alimentation) (for learning purposes).
But the problem however is that I cannot find any reference to next page  in the HTML source code. Since the website uses infinite scrolling.
I suspect this has a relation with what I am seeking, but even though if it was, I don't know how to extract next page from it.

```
<div id="searchPageSpinner" class="search-loader-full hidden">
    <svg class="svg cocote-logo" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 200" enable-background="new 0 0 275 200" xml:space="preserve">
[...]
</div>
```

What I tried gives me the expected results, however, it's a too basic and simple idea.
I create a list of requests with an random length (I got the length using dichotomy), that is slightly superior than the number of pages I wanna scrape. It's 1000 in this example.

```
        return [FormRequest(url=url,
                             formdata={'query': '/s/c/alimentation/offset/{}'.format(i)},
                             meta=meta,
                             method=method,
                             callback=self.parse)
                   for i in range(1000)]
```

Here is the full code I am using:

```py
class CocoteSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    Blessed are the cheesemakers. For they shall inherit the Earth.
    """
    name = 'cocote_products_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['cocote.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        """
        Send search request.
        """
        url = 'https://fr.cocote.com/page'

        meta = {
            'handle_httpstatus_all': True,
            }

        method = 'POST'

        return [FormRequest(url=url,
                             formdata={'query': '/s/c/alimentation/offset/{}'.format(i)},
                             meta=meta,
                             method=method,
                             callback=self.parse)
                   for i in range(1000)]

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        Parse search results and extracting some item fields.
        """
        unformated_data = response.body
        twelve_producers_id = list(set(re.findall('href="/p/(.+?)"', unformated_data)))
        main_url = 'https://fr.cocote.com/p/'
        for producer_id in twelve_producers_id:
            link = main_url + producer_id
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_products)
```

What I actually want is to learn a new method to deal with websites that are using infinite scrolling with scrapy. 
I looked over the Internet, but the suggested solutions doesn't match what I am seeking.

Thank you for reading my question, double thanks for your answer, and have a wonderful day in both cases!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the response you get back, you can see the total number here:
`response.xpath('//*[@id="totalResultSearch"]/@value')`. You can base yourself on this to figure out how many requests you should make like this.
From the original page, you can also find this count back here: `response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/@value')`.
You can rewrite the start_requests & parse like this to get the right products:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import FormRequest


class CocoteSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    Blessed are the cheesemakers. For they shall inherit the Earth.
    """
    name = 'cocote_products_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['cocote.com']
    start_urls = ['https://fr.cocote.com/s/c/alimentation']

    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://fr.cocote.com/page'
        total = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="search-results"]/@value'
        ).extract_first()
        offset = 12
        for i in range(0, int(total), offset):
            query = '/s/c/alimentation/offset/{}'.format(i)
            yield FormRequest(url=url,
                              formdata={'query': query},
                              method='POST',
                              callback=self.parse_result
                              )

    def parse_result(self, response):
        ...
```

Another, more generic solution is to mimic the scrolling behaviour by rendering the pages using something like [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and write a custom script that scrolls down.

Comment: It should be `for i in range(0, int(total), 12):`